# Highcharts: how to generate a few charts plus non-chart text in a single downloadable pdf file

Tags: highcharts

I have a web page that has text AND a few Highcharts charts. I would like to provide a button to export ALL of them  in a single PDF.

I did research and was unable to find a client-side tool that can do this with Unicode support. It seems that it has to be the server-side solution. And it seems to me that this may involve a few tools other than just Highcharts.

I am new to Highcharts. I would like to know how this can be accomplished technically, the flow, and what tools are needed.

I also have a question. How can a Highcharts chart be generated on the server-side and then put into a PDF document? Put it another way, can I generate the image or something of a Highcharts chart within a program, and then within the program, put it into a document (PDF) later?

Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Just a note: Highcharts exporting server works only with SVG. Then you need another solution, like wkhtmltopdf or any different solution. Remember to disable animations on your site before exporting anything.

Comment: Pawel, thanks for your input. wkhtmltopdf is basically a command line tool, which seems it will not scale well. wkhtmltopdf has a C library, but I use Java. I am wondering how other people do for similar needs, considering Highcharts is such a popular charting tool.

Comment: Maybe old solution from Highcharts exporting server? Batik rasterizer. In general, probably searching web for 'export html page to pdf in java' should help ;)